# Why Rust compiler didn't stop me from mutating const data type using smart pointer RefCell?

Tags: rust, constants, smart-pointers

I was surprised to see the smart pointer RefCell can mutate any type of data as I expect to mutate even const. Why const data cannot be mutated via smart pointers? If I considered the const can never be changed then why the attempt to modify const data executed successfully?

```
 const NAME : RefCell<&str> = RefCell::new("XYZ");
    println!("The const NAME is: {}",*NAME.borrow_mut());

 *NAME.borrow_mut() = "abc";
    println!("The mutated NAME is: {}",*NAME.borrow());
```

I exactly want to know why the const data is not modified even the compiler executed the code successfully. I expect the compiler will stop me from doing that modification but actually it didn't? Here is the output,

```
The name is: XYZ
The mutated name is: XYZ
```

Comment: Atleast compiler need to warn us that we r if creating an instance of const,I got it, const are values not memory space actually, I just want to know why compiler says nothing about that???

Comment: For what it's worth, `clippy` does warn (and in fact gives an error) when a constant has interior mutability.

Comment: `RefCell` is not _quite_ a smart pointer => it does not allocate or deallocate memory.